# C# Charts: delete empty columns and show all column names

Tags: c#, charts, stacked-chart

I would like to delete empty columns, I mean by that: if a column has total value of 0 --> remove its space and its name.
I would like also to show every single column names below the X axis.
Is that possible?
Here is my code example and a png of what I have now.

[image: My StackedColumn example]

```
chart1.Series.Add("Series1");
chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("column1", 6);
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("column2", 0);
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("column3", 11);
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("column4",6);
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("column5", 0);
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("column6",0);
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("column7", 6);
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("column8", 0);
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("column9",2 );
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("column10",6);
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("column11", 0);
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("column12", 5);
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("column13",0);
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("column14", 0);

chart1.Series.Add("Series2");
chart1.Series["Series2"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("column1", 3);
chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("column2", 0);
chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("column3", 7);
chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("column4", 0);
chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("column5", 0);
chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("column6", 3);
chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("column7", 5);
chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("column8", 3);
chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("column9", 6);
chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("column10", 3);
chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("column11", 0);
chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("column12", 6);
chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("column13", 0);
chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("column14", 3);

chart1.Titles.Add("Series View by StackedColumns"); 
chart1.Titles[0].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("consolas", 15f);   
chart1.Legends[0].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("consolas", 15f);          
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = true;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: Well the columns are not empty, just small. You will have to loop over the points and where y-values of both/all series are 0, remove the points. To show all labels you need enough space.

Comment: Ok thx! I managed to get what I wanted. Here is the code:

Answer (score 1):

Thx, First to see all column names simply add this line of code:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
```

Then to loop over the points and remove values if total is zero:

```
for (int i = 0; i < chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.Count;i++)
{
    if(chart1.Series["Series1"].Points[i].YValues[0] + 
       chart1.Series["Series2"].Points[i].YValues[0] == 0)
    {
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.Remove(chart1.Series["Series1"].Points[i]);
        chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.Remove(chart1.Series["Series2"].Points[i]);
    }
}
```